# rename a column in all the tables - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to rename a column in all tables in my database. 
so a column 'OldColumn' has to be renamed to 'NewColumn' in all the tables

I could get list of tables that has this column using this query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME= <Column Name>
```

But how can i rename it in all tables as simple as possible and don't have to write a cursor?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a cursor?

Comment: I really don't **think** this is possible **without** a cursor, but I could be wrong. Regardless, this is one of the *fewer* times I'd find a cursor appropriate.

Comment: I agree, cursor seems fine here to rename a few columns.

Comment: well you could take the results of the query, write them out to excel or notepad++ and then write the `'=RENAME COLUMN ' &A1& '.Column TO newCol;'` using formula and fill series down..  no cursor, no typing of query and simple fill down in excel to generate the X number of rename statements.

Comment: It can certainly be done without a cursor...but hopefully you don't have that many columns all with the same name you suddenly want to change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course you don't need a cursor for this. You can use sys.columns and sys.objects to generate dynamic sql. Then simply execute it. Once you are satisfied the dynamic sql is what you want feel free to uncomment the last line.

----BE WARNED!!!!----
If you change column names your views, stored procedures, functions etc will all be broken.

```
declare @CurrentColumnName sysname = 'asdf'
    , @NewColumnName sysname = 'qwer'
    , @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'EXEC sp_rename ''' + o.name + '.' + c.name + ''', ''' + @NewColumnName + ''', ''COLUMN'';'
from sys.columns c
join sys.objects o on o.object_id = c.object_id
where c.name = @CurrentColumnName

select @SQL

--exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: I didn't think about doing it dynamically... SMRT

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, this will generate the script

```
select 'EXEC sp_rename ' + tableName + ''' OldColumn''' + ' ' +  '''NewColumn'''
from 
(select distinct OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) tableName from sys.columns where name like '%DUNS%')a
```

Comment: This does nothing to rename the column in all tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate scripts like this and then execute it in one go:

```
declare @oldColumn nvarchar(max) = 'department_id'
declare @newColumn varchar(max) = 'dept_id'
declare @query nvarchar(max) 

select 'exec sp_rename '+ char(39) + table_name + '.' + @oldColumn + char(39)
    +', '+ char(39) + @newColumn + char(39) + ','+ char(39) + 'COLUMN' +Char(39) + ' GO ' from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME = 'department_id'
```

Generated script for your reference:

```
exec sp_rename 'table5.department_id', 'dept_id','COLUMN' 
exec sp_rename 'table6.department_id', 'dept_id','COLUMN'  
exec sp_rename 'table1.department_id', 'dept_id','COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 0):

The below dynamically takes all of the table names in the DB that contain a given column name, in this case 'COL_A', and inserts those names into a table, in this case 'DBO.QUEUE'.  That table then acts as a queue for the cursor below. Dynamic SQL was used to iterate through the queue and call sp_RENAME to rename the column in every applicable table.

```
--The below two tables will be found and update
CREATE TABLE DBO.TEST1 (COL_A INT)
CREATE TABLE DBO.TEST2 (COL_A INT)

--The below will NOT update
CREATE TABLE DBO.TEST3 (COL_B INT)

--Create a table to act as a queue
CREATE TABLE DBO.QUEUE (TABLENAME VARCHAR(255))

--Insert into the queue based upon your criteria
INSERT INTO QUEUE
SELECT DISTINCT(TABLE_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME= 'COL_A'

--Run the cursor to update
DECLARE 

 @TABLENAME VARCHAR(255)

DECLARE Cursor_Name CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
            SELECT 
                        TABLENAME
            FROM 
                        DBO.QUEUE AS LIST;


OPEN Cursor_Name
FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_Name INTO @TABLENAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

--Dynamic SQL is used to execute the sp_Rename procedure with the applicable table name.
Declare @colupdate_ varchar(MAX)
set @colupdate_= 
'EXEC sp_RENAME ' + '"' + @TABLENAME + '.' + 'COL_A' + '"' + ',' + '"' + 'NEW_COLUMN_NAME' + '"' + ',' + '"' +'COLUMN' + '"'
exec(@colupdate_)

FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_Name INTO @TABLENAME
END

CLOSE Cursor_Name
DEALLOCATE Cursor_Name
```