# Writing a query to generate some scripts to rename some columns in entire database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

I have a SQL Server 2019 database (a big one). This database has about 3000 columns and about 200 tables and for each table we have at least 3 stored procedures.

Anyway we have some columns in this database that start with lower case letters, like `userID`. They should be `UserID`. My boss said that we should rename all these columns. I used a `Select` statement to find these columns.

Here is the code :

```
select * from information_schema.columns where ascii(left(column_name, 1)) between ascii('a') and ascii('z');
```

So I have The Column Name , Table Name And Also Schema Name .
I want a Query For Generate Some Scripts To Rename These Columns That Start With Upper Case Letter in Entire Database .(Procedures , Tables , Views and .....)

The query Should Generate Scripts Like this :

```
Alter [sch].[tableName] Alter Column ColumnName INT
```

If There Is A Better Way Let me Know .

i want The Query or Procedure to Do This .

Thank You So Much ...

Comment: To rename an object you need to use `sys.sp_rename`, not `ALTER`. [sp_rename (Transact SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: If you database is in a Case Insensitive collation, however, why does this matter? `UserID`, `userId`, `USERID` would all successfully reference the column. If, however, you're using a Case Sensitive collation this is going to be a huge breaking change.

Comment: use your query to produce lines with `sys.sp_rename` for each column that needs changing, and then copy all lines and paste them in SSMS

Comment: But have you asked your boss why this change is needed ? If you are on a Case Sensitive Collation this change can bring you weeks of work to get all functioning again, and if not then it does not matters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rename a column in all the tables - SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142683/rename-a-column-in-all-the-tables-sql)

Comment: A skill you need to develop is searching the internet for useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Although renaming the table column is not difficult using `sp_rename`, changing the referencing views and stored procedures is non-trivial without the help of tools.

The T-SQL below will generate script to rename all columns that start with a lower case letter. However, it is fragile in that renames will fail when enforced dependencies exist (e.g. schema bound objects) and will not handle views, procs. et. al.

```
SELECT 
      N'EXEC sp_rename ''' 
    + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(c.name) 
    + ''', ''' + UPPER(LEFT(c.name, 1)) + SUBSTRING(c.name,2,127) + ''', ''COLUMN'';'
FROM sys.schemas AS s
JOIN sys.tables AS t ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
JOIN sys.columns AS c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE 
    LEFT(c.name, 1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS <> UPPER(LEFT(c.name, 1)) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0;
```

I suggest you use [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15), which is included with Visual Studio 2019 (including the free Community Edition). Create a new SQL Server Database Project, import the existing database, rename the column using the Refactor-->Rename option, and then publish the project against the target database. Publish provides the option to apply the changes immediately and/or just generate the script. The script will include DDL for the column rename as will as change the column name in all referencing objects.

If the column is aliased with the undesired name in views, procs, etc., those aliases will also need to be changed.

Comment: I want a Query To Generate Alter Scripts For Each Record Of my Select Statement In a Format Like :

ALTER TABLE [TableName] RENAME COLUMN [OldColumnName] TO [NewColumnName];
or Like This One :

ALTER TABLE TableName CHANGE COLUMN OldColumnName NewColumnName Data Type;
The old [Old_Column_Name] Start With Lower Case Letter, so the [New_Column_Name] Should Start With Upper Case Letter .

for Example : old Name = user ===> New Name = User

Comment: `RENAME COLUMN` isn't valid T-SQL, @ImanS3 . See the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66439068/writing-a-query-to-generate-some-scripts-to-rename-some-columns-in-entire-databa#comment117455841_66439068) I wrote 2~ hours ago under your question.

Comment: 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name. @DanGuzman

Comment: @Larnu Yes i Get that . i have a Code Like this : select 'EXEC sp_rename '''+TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME+'.'+COLUMN_NAME+''', '''+CHAR( ASCII(LEFT(COLUMN_NAME,1))-32 ) + SUBSTRING(COLUMN_NAME,2,LEN(COLUMN_NAME))+''', ''COLUMN'';  '
from information_schema.columns where ascii(left(column_name, 1)) between ascii('a') and ascii('z');   it Works , But i want To Write the select output  Recordes in a .sql file .

Comment: *"'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name."* Then you aren't using SQL Server 2019 like you have tagged, @ImanS3 . Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) `STRING_AGG` is available in **any** compatiblity mode.

Comment: @Larnu I am Using SSMS V18.7.1

Comment: That's your version of SSMS, @ImanS3 , that has nothing to do with the version of SQL Server you are using. SSMS is just an IDE for SQL Server.

Comment: @ImanS3, I removed the `STRING_AGG` from my answer since you are using an older version of SQL Server. Just copy all the rows in the results and execute.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank You So Much . can we Do something For procedures and References ?

Comment: @ImanS3, yes, use SSDT as I mentioned in my answer. Changing procs, views, etc. cannot be done reliably with T-SQL alone.