# Writing an Script That Makes Alter Query For Target Objects in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

I have a List Of Columns Which Started With Lower case Letters . this List Have 270 Record , It means That I have 270 Column Name in Data Base that Should Rename To start with Upper Case Letter .
I Have the List With This Script :

```
select * from information_schema.columns where ascii(left(column_name, 1)) between ascii('a') and ascii('z');
```

I want a Query To Generate Alter Scripts For Each Record Of my Select Statement In a Format Like :

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] RENAME COLUMN [OldColumnName] TO [NewColumnName];
```

or Like This One :

```
ALTER TABLE TableName CHANGE COLUMN OldColumnName NewColumnName Data Type;
```

The old [Old_Column_Name] Start With Lower Case Letter, so the [New_Column_Name] Should Start With Upper Case Letter .

for Example : old Name = user  ===>  New Name = User

Thanks.

Comment: what did you try so far? you can do this with string concatenation, then execute the output in an editor

Comment: Are you sure that object and column names are case-sensitive on your SqlServer installation?  They usually aren't, even if they remember what case you used when you created them, that does not necessarily mean that a table's column names will allow two names with the same spelling but different cases.

Comment: Or to put it another way, have you tried any of these commands individually and confirmed if they actually work on your database (that is, that the column name actually changes its case)?  It's easy enough to produce the combined ALTER scripts, it's a bit harder for us to be sure if the names will actually get changed correctly for your database.

Comment: Why did you just repost the same thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66439068/writing-a-query-to-generate-some-scripts-to-rename-some-columns-in-entire-databa

Comment: Also, what kind of output are you looking for?   A copy and paste script based on your current database (easy) or a stored procedure that can be re-executed at will?

Comment: Technically this is NOT a duplicate as the OP has re-stated his original question to here to clarify that the answer provided there (to his first question) was not what they wanted (even though it was a correct answer to the original wording.

Comment: I disagree, @RBarryYoung, the OP doesn't even reference their prior question, nor have they read the comments from it, as they are (again), attempting to try to use some non-existant `ALTER TABLE` syntax for renaming. Of course, I can't close this again, but this is most certainly a duplicate. Especially when the 2 answers are effectively the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's still not entirely clear to me what you are looking for, and whether this will actually change the case names in your database (settings vary), the following should work:

```
select 'EXEC sp_rename '''+TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME+'.'+COLUMN_NAME+''', '''
    +CHAR( ASCII(LEFT(COLUMN_NAME,1))-32 ) + SUBSTRING(COLUMN_NAME,2,LEN(COLUMN_NAME))
    +''', ''COLUMN'';  '
from information_schema.columns where ascii(left(column_name, 1)) between ascii('a') and ascii('z');
```

Comment: That's It. Thank You .But can you Develop this to Rename a Column Name in All References Like Procedures ? can You Change it To Write Select output one by one in a .sql file ? @RBarryYoung

Comment: @ImanS3  Just copy-and-paste the output to whatever file you want.

Comment: There is Over 270 Record !!! there most be a way @RBarryYoung

Comment: @ImanS3 Just copy them all at once into your .sql file.  Or use the SSMS menu and just save the output as a file.  I don't understand the problem here?

Comment: What about Changing References ? Stored Procedures and views ? can I do Something For them in this Code?

Comment: When injecting values into a dynamic query, you need to ensure you use `QUOTENAME` or (as would be required in this case), properly escape the values using `REPLACE`. Otherwise you *could* end up with undesired behaviour or errors. For the above, that would be if there is a poorly named object with a  single quote (`'`) in its name.